# How to dump text on one line without brackets and commas into Pickle file

Tags: python, file, pickle

I am writing a currency converter and one of the parts is a program which allows you to check and change the conversion rates between Pound Sterling and three other currencies. Whilst the actual conversion is fine, I have a problem with exporting the new rates into a pickle file on a single line. This is because, the rates are written in a pickle file in the format:
Pound-Sterling 1 Euro 1.15 US-Dollar 1.3 etc.

I would appreciate any help.

I've tried simply dumping a list and tuple, however it simply doesn't work - it is not a Python error, but a logical one.

```
import pickle

Currencies = "Pound-Sterling", "Euro", "US-Dollar", "Japanese-Yen"
Displayed = {}
Exchange_rates = pickle.load(open("rates.pkl","rb"))

print("This program allows you to check and change the currency conversion rates before using the converter program.")

for Line in Exchange_rates:
    if not "Pound-Sterling" in Line:
        Displayed_key = Line.split(" ")[0]
        Displayed_value = Line.split(" ")[1]
        Displayed[Displayed_key] = Displayed_value
        print("£1 is", Line)

Exchange_rates = {}
New_rates = open("rates.pkl","wb")
pickle.dump("",New_rates)
pickle.dump("Pound-Sterling 1",New_rates)

if getYesNo("Do you want to change an exchange rate for a currency (Y/N):"):
    for i in range(1,4):
        Currency = Currencies[i]
        print("£1 is", Currency, Displayed[Currency])
        Prompt = "Please input the new rate for", Currency, ":"
        Prompt = " ".join(Prompt)
        New_rate = float(input(Prompt))
        To_append = Currency, New_rate
        pickle.dump(To_append,New_rates)

New_rates.close()
```

The new pickle file should be in the original format on one single line. Instead, it is either on many lines or doesn't work and, furthermore, I cannot get rid of the brackets and commas.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have chosen to make use of pickling for this program? Pickling is generally intended to be used when storing more complex data structures than a few string, float pairs.

Comment: this line `To_append = Currency, New_rate` creates a tuple not a space separated string. To improve your python I recommend submitting this (once working) to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as there are some glaring ways you could improve this such as using the canonical way to open and read from a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version of your code with some improvements

Improvements:

1. We don't want to worry about closing files so we use `with open('Currencies.pkl', 'rb') as f:`. This is called a context manager and takes care of closing the file.
2. Code we want to reuse has been put into callable functions like `print_currencies`
3. Changing `for i in range(1,4):` to `for currency in CURRENCIES:` is both more readable and allows any number of currencies. `CURRENCIES` here is a dictionary but could be a list or any iterable.
4. I've pickled a python dictionary object to store the currencies.

Areas to improve:

1. I've repeated 'Currencies.pkl' in the code
2. I don't ask if user want to close program
3. What if I want to leave currency as is?

```
import pickle

# I'll use this later to test if pickle file exists
import os.path

# let's use a default dictionary object
CURRENCIES = {
    "Pound-Sterling": 1,
    "Euro": 1,
    "US-Dollar": 1,
    "Japanese-Yen": 1
}

def load_currencies():
    """Load a dictionary object of currencies previously stored"""
    with open('Currencies.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        dict = pickle.load(f)
    return dict

def dump_currencies(dict):
    """Dump a dictionary object of currencies"""
    with open('Currencies.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(dict, f)

def print_currencies(dict):
    for currency in dict:
        if currency != "Pound-Sterling":
             print("£1 is", dict[currency], currency)

# this is a special line of code that says "Hey if run me
# directly run this code but if you import me don't"
#  - the code that runs effectively starts from here
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # if our pickle file does not exist create it using the default
    if not os.path.isfile('Currencies.pkl'):
        dump_currencies(CURRENCIES)

    print("This program allows you to check and change the currency conversion rates before using the converter program.")

    CURRENCIES = load_currencies()

    print_currencies(CURRENCIES)

    answer = input("Do you want to change an exchange rate for a currency (Y/N):")
    if answer == 'Y':
        for currency in CURRENCIES:
            # print(currency) 
            # print(type(currency)) <-- string
            print("£1 is", CURRENCIES[currency], currency)
            New_rate = float(input("Please input the new rate for "+currency+":"))
            CURRENCIES[currency] = New_rate
        dump_currencies(CURRENCIES)
```